# Hide values from the Angular Material multiple drop down list

Tags: angular-material, angular8

How can I hide the values in the drop down box. What I want to achieve is just a placeholder without showing the values selected from multiple. I should keep this `ngmodel and selectionChange` for other purposes. 
Is there any way?

[image]

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select
        placeholder="Select Columns"
        (selectionChange)="columnSelect()"
        multiple
        [(ngModel)]="selectedColumns"
    >
        <mat-option
            *ngFor="let c of fixedColumns"
            [value]="c"
        >
            {{ c }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding mat-select-trigger;

```
<mat-select
    (selectionChange)="columnSelect()"
    multiple
    [(ngModel)]="selectedColumns"
>
    <mat-select-trigger class="trigger">
        Select Columns
    </mat-select-trigger>
    <mat-option
        *ngFor="let c of fixedColumns"
        [value]="c"
    >
        {{ c }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>

``
```